# Trying to scraping multiples divs with same name but getting null instead

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, html-agility-pack

Hi I am try to scrape multiple divs having same class name using

> htmlagilitypack nugat pakge

but i am getting null in the final step .I cant able to figure out the problem.

I have installed both nuget pakges of Htmlagilitypack i mean simple and for .netcore

Here is the code that I am trying in my controller (ASP.NET MVC Core)

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
var html = @"https://www.indeed.com.pk/jobs?q=software+engineer&l=Rawalpindi";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
var htmlDoc = web.Load(html);
var node3 = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'jobsearch-SerpJobCard')]");
//node3 coming out null
ViewData["Data"] = node3;
return View();
}
```

What I want is to send all these job posting on that provided link which i am trying to scrape to sent on my view.

Comment: If the selection returns null then your xpath query does not match anything in the document. Can you show us what the content of the HTML doc looks like?

Comment: You can see it by visiting the link which i provided https://www.indeed.com.pk/jobs?q=software+engineer&l=Rawalpindi

Comment: Is above code all your complete code?I tried and it also works well with HtmlAgilityPack 1.11.12 asp.net core 2.2 MVC app.Could you create a new 2.2 mvc project to have a test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code and for me it's working correctly, node3 has 30 results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BA0T0.jpg. Either there is something else in your code that is missing from your post, or you are getting a different version of the website in your program due to region-locked content or something. I'd check `htmlDoc` for whether its content is the same as what you get in your browser.

Comment: May be that's because you are running it on the console programe? Not in ASP.NET Core Web app

Comment: Should not make a difference to be honest, can you verify that the HTML downloaded by HtmlAgilityPack and the one you get in your browser are identical?

Comment: I double check both  are same . You are running it in under .netcore ? Right !

Comment: Correct, running under .NET Core 2.2, using HtmlAgilityPack 1.11.12. For reference, here is the HTML from the `htmlDoc` when I run the program: https://pastebin.com/asP59YTV. Is it the same as for you? Can you verify that if you try to parse this HTML on your end, it works correctly?

Comment: I verified with the HTML you provided as well and it's working also, with 30 results. Are you using the newest version of HtmlAgilityPack?

Comment: I also tried an approach with HttpClient (which you should probably use in ASP.NET Core also) here on dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MvM9eL and it is working also.

Comment: That's too strange why its not work on my side under .NET Core 2.2, using HtmlAgilityPack 1.11.12.